# kubenetes can'n not get nodes info after approve certificate from kubelet

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I install kubernetes with the way of manual. I can't get nodes info after master approve request of certificate from kubelet .

First , `etcd` `kube-apiserver`  `kube-controller-manager` and `kube-scheduler` have been installed correctly. Execute commands `kubectl get cs` got  the follow output :

```
[root@master cfg]# kubectl get cs
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
scheduler            Healthy   ok
etcd-2               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
```

Then , I try to install kubelet on master node and a worker node .
On master node execute command `kubectl approve node-csr-V_FXPiKHAtqS_9GH27RCk6hPNWE0nF8bLSH6Ot7C360`  and `kubectl get csr`:

```
[root@master cfg]# kubectl get csr
NAME                                                   AGE    SIGNERNAME                                    REQUESTOR           CONDITION
node-csr-Tbrw3ia-c0D7kgIURIe_JnP1PCEdwf9XeATP0KcsyBg   111m   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   kubelet-bootstrap   Approved,Issued
node-csr-V_FXPiKHAtqS_9GH27RCk6hPNWE0nF8bLSH6Ot7C360   131m   kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client-kubelet   kubelet-bootstrap   Approved,Issued
```

However,  I can't get nodes from this cluster:

```
[root@master cfg]# kubectl get node
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Any body can take me a hand ? Looking forward your help or something ideas to trace the problem.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had found the reason of this problem. Service of `kubelet` on master node and worker node don't really up .
I got error from /var/log/message , follow :

```
Dec 11 21:21:20 worker1 systemd: Started Kubernetes Kubelet.
Dec 11 21:21:20 worker1 systemd: Starting Kubernetes Kubelet...
Dec 11 21:21:20 worker1 systemd: Started Kubernetes systemd probe.
Dec 11 21:21:20 worker1 systemd: Starting Kubernetes systemd probe.
Dec 11 21:21:20 worker1 kubelet: F1211 21:21:20.905947    3066 server.go:274] failed to run Kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs" is different from docker cgroup driver: "systemd"
```

which means docker's `cgroup driver` config  is conflict with kubelet .
After updated docker service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`,  set `--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs` :

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target
Wants=docker-storage-setup.service
Requires=docker-cleanup.timer

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=main
EnvironmentFile=-/run/containers/registries.conf
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-storage
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker-network
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash
Environment=DOCKER_HTTP_HOST_COMPAT=1
Environment=PATH=/usr/libexec/docker:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-current \
          --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current \
          --default-runtime=docker-runc \
          --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs \
          --userland-proxy-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-proxy-current \
          --init-path=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current \
          --seccomp-profile=/etc/docker/seccomp.json \
          $OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS \
          $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS \
          $ADD_REGISTRY \
          $BLOCK_REGISTRY \
          $INSECURE_REGISTRY \
          $REGISTRIES
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-abnormal
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, restart docker and kubelet service , problem had been solved. Service `kubelet` work correctly .

Execute command `kubelet get nodes` , output follow :

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
master    NotReady   <none>   8s     v1.18.3
worker1   NotReady   <none>   112s   v1.18.3
```